# How to use display image in Salesforce flow?

Tags: community, visual-workflow, workflow, visual-flows, screen-flow

[image]
I could not figure it out. How can we display image in the screen flow?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_display_image.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to first upload the image as a Static Resource, then reference the name of the Static Resource in your flow

For more information, please see: https://laptrinhx.com/how-to-use-images-as-static-resource-in-salesforce-flow-3708551091/

Comment: Hi Andy, please post a more complete answer rather than just a link, Thanks :)

Comment: Apparently I don’t understand the code of conduct here very well. I did not like the platform much. I stopped posting.